# Mod mono serves different web application instance over SSH

Tags: asp.net, apache, ssh, mono, application-pool

I have one asp.net application running on latest Mod mono  When I access it through url

```
1. http://myServer.com/App
```

or

```
2. http://localhost:81/App
```

I get different instances for each address. How do I know there are different? Through examining Application_Start which actually fires twice and asp.net Application variables which have different values.

I use the second address only when I want to connect to my server through SSH, and I use local port forwarding so that each request that is sent from my computer on port 81 is actualy forwarded to port 80 on my server.

Both addresses point to the same phisycal location and I don't understand why there are actually two different instances behind each one?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Specific example:

this is how I store time of the application start event in Global.asax.cs

```
    public static string AppStartTime;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppStartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

This are the parameters for **plink.exe** used for remote port forwarding to remote Apache server:

```
    -L :7787:localhost:80
```

If I use plink 3 times with 3 different ports, 3 different time values are displayed when I visit the same web application through different url.

```
    http://localhost:7787/ => value of AppStartTime = time1

    http://localhost:7788/ => value of AppStartTime = time2

    http://localhost:7789/ => value of AppStartTime = time3
```

Comment: Mono 2.6.7 is *ancient*. Please upgrade to 2.10.x or 3.0

Comment: We upgraded it to mono 2.11.4, mod_mono 2.10. But I stil have the sane problem.

Answer (score 1):

This question concerns a web server configuration issue, and is unrelated to Mono. It seems as though you have two virtual servers / websites configured in Apache, rather than a single virtual server with two different bindings.

Change your configuration so you have a single virtual server with both bindings set up and you will have a single instance in-memory.

Comment: Actualy it's not myServer it is my companies server. But I have access to all aspects of apache/mono configuration. But I dont get it. Why is a different instance served only when accessing it through SSH. Is that a security thing? All other variations of accessing it give me instance 1. only access through SSH gives me instance 2. ??

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I'm working on a similar config issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480328

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. It's a very small ammount of data that gets accessed unfrequently so I changed my architecture to use file storage instead.